# How to know when a vm script finishes execution?

Tags: node.js

Here is a sample code:

```js
const vm = require('vm');

// Pass setTimeout function to the sandbox
const sandbox = { setTimeout };

// Will assign 'stackoverflow' to global variable `test` after 2 seconds
const rawCode = 'setTimeout(() => { test = "stackoverflow"; }, 2000);';

const script = new vm.Script(rawCode);
script.runInNewContext(sandbox);

// Output: {
//  setTimeout: [Function: setTimeout] { [Symbol(util.promisify.custom)]: [Function] }
// }
console.log(sandbox);

// Output: {
//  setTimeout: [Function: setTimeout] { [Symbol(util.promisify.custom)]: [Function] },
//  test: 'stackoverflow'
// }
setTimeout(() => console.log(sandbox), 2000);
```

Is there any way to tell that the code in the vm's context is fully executed and there are no callbacks left in its event loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/3020#issuecomment-144117993) comment on Github (written by [bnoordhuis](https://github.com/bnoordhuis)):

> Contexts share the event loop.

So if we call `setTimeout` in VM code, the callback is registered in the same queue with the "parent". There is no way to tell if the callback belongs to VM code or to the parent after that. Therefore we cannot track the number of registered callbacks in VM and cannot tell when it finishes running.

I have created [a feature request on Node.js project](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/31240) but apparently there are significant challenges to overcome.